# Gmod: run commands on startup with addon

Tags: lua, add-on, garrys-mod

YES this is a gmod and a lua question!
I would like to know if its possible to run LUA commands though an addon when the user has just launched the game and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to run Lua commands in the menu state when the user has launched the game. This is unless you mean when they first spawn into a map, which is possible - and is what I'm about to describe.

You can use the hook system to hook onto events that happen in the game. One of these hooks is `Initialize` which is called when the game first loads and Lua is initialized. Another option is `InitPostEntity` which is called after all map entities have been spawned.

To use the hook system, call `hook.Add("Hook name", "Custom identifier", function(...) end)`

For example, to use the `Initialize` hook, use this code:

```
hook.Add("Initialize", "myidentifier", function()
    -- put your code here
end)
```

Comment: That's not what i meant but thank you fore telling me. :D i hope someone dose find a way though...